# How to disable client side validation field wise

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

suppose my form has 5 fields and first two will be validated at client side and next one will not but next will. i got the guidance like

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BatchId, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
</div>
```

but it did not work. i wrote `Html.EnableClientValidation(true)`

and after second field and before 3rd field i wrote `Html.EnableClientValidation(false)`
and again i wrote `Html.EnableClientValidation(true)` before 4th field. but i saw all fields are getting validated at client side.
thanks

Comment: How are you setting the fields validation? You are using strongly typed views? Please add more code so we can better diagnose the problem. (view code, controller code, view model code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `@Html.TexBoxFor(model => model.BatchId, new {@class = "k-textbox", data_val = false})`

That should disable validation for field

Comment: thanks for the answer. can u plzz tell me how could i use fancy jquery plugin for validation instead of unobtrusive plugin but i want to use data annotation and also i want data annotation will emit the new plugin. so what & where i need to customize in code.

Comment: here u use @class="" the @ sign is mandatory ? but data_val has no @ sign as prefix....so when to use @ when adding attribute ? can guide me briefly. thanks

Comment: class is a .net reserved keyword so needs the @. If the answer has helped please considered upvoting. I don't use fancy jquery plugin so can't help there Im afarid