# How to skip client side validation in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a model

```
public class ProductModels
{

    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SubCatId { get; set; }



}
```

I can skip the server side validation by using following :

`ModelState.Remove("ProductName");
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
  }`

Field made [Required] in model, but I want to skip this required field validation on client side, when user perfom any post event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816898/how-to-disable-client-side-validation-field-wise

Comment: you want to disable client side validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore the properties you don't want to validate. You can do this do this by following code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore"
})
```

If you are using unobtrusive validation, just set the default.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: ":hidden .ignore" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Web.config which is outside your views Directory.

and set the following in

```
<appSettings>

     <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

let me know if you need any further help

Answer (score 0):

```
To get rid of controller IsValid , use basecontroller to deal with that

 public class ResourceController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: /Resource/GetResources
        const int durationInSeconds = 2 * 60 * 60;  // 2 hours.

        /// <summary>
        /// Fetches resouces for javascript queries.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "culture", Duration = durationInSeconds)]
        public JsonResult GetResources()
        {
            return Json(
                typeof(Resource)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(p => !p.Name.IsLikeAny("ResourceManager", "Culture")) // Skip the properties you don't need on the client side.
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(null) as string)
                 , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   

        }
```